# Computing NTILE in R for RFM analysis

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a dataframe computing 10 percentiles based on the Recency, Frequency and Monetary. I have most of it set up, but I can't figure out why my code is returning three NTILES, when I'm asking for 10. I'm currently at a stand still. The next step will be calculating the percentage of customers in each ntile.

Here is my code:

```
rm(list = ls())
setwd("/Users/a76475/Documents/Customer_Analytics")
rfm<-read.csv("cdnow_students_transaction.csv")

#Set up test and calibration samples   
rfm$DATE <- as.Date(rfm$DATE, format = "%m/%d/%y")
calib <- subset(rfm, rfm$DATE<"1997-09-29")
valid <- subset(rfm, rfm$DATE>"1997-09-30")

#Aggregate for frequency, monetary, and recency -- Calibration
recency<- aggregate(DATE ~ ID, data =calib, FUN = max)
colnames(recency) <- c("ID","Recency")
frequency <- aggregate(DOLLARS ~ ID, data =calib, FUN = length)
colnames(frequency) <- c("ID","Frequency")
monetary <- aggregate(DOLLARS ~ ID, data =calib, FUN = mean)
colnames(frequency) <- c("ID","Monetary")
calib <- merge(frequency, monetary, by = "ID")
calib <- merge(calib, recency, by = "ID")

#Aggregate for frequency, monetary, and recency -- Validation
recency<- aggregate(DATE ~ ID, data =valid, FUN = max)
colnames(recency) <- c("ID","Recency") 
frequency <- aggregate(DOLLARS ~ ID, data =valid, FUN = length)
colnames(frequency) <- c("ID","Frequency")
monetary <- aggregate(DOLLARS ~ ID, data =valid, FUN = mean)
colnames(frequency) <- c("ID","Monetary")
valid <- merge(frequency, monetary, by = "ID")
valid <- merge(valid, recency, by = "ID")

colnames(valid) <- c("ID","FREQ","MONETARY","RECENCY")
colnames(calib) <- c("ID","FREQ","MONETARY","RECENCY")
calib$RECENCY <- NULL

#Create recency score
#For validation
for (i in 1:nrow(valid)) {
  valid$RECENCY1[i] = as.numeric(max(valid$RECENCY) - valid$RECENCY[i])
}
valid$RECENCY <- valid$RECENCY1
valid$RECENCY1 <- NULL

#For calibration
for (i in 1:nrow(calib)) {
  calib$RECENCY1[i] = as.numeric(max(valid$RECENCY) - calib$RECENCY[i])
}
calib$RECENCY <- calib$RECENCY1
calib$RECENCY1 <- NULL

#Merge datasets
rfm <- merge(calib,valid, by="ID", all.x = TRUE)

#Create Column for retention%
require(dplyr)
rfm$monetary.ntile <- ntile(rfm$MONETARY.y,10)
rfm$freq.ntile <- ntile(rfm$FREQ.y,10)
rfm$recency.ntile <- ntile(rfm$RECENCY,10)
```

Comment: Nathan-Luke, welcome to StackOverflow. To make it easier to help, please read (1) [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), (2) [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as (3) [how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then I suggest you edit and improve your question accordingly. I.e., provide some artificial input data (many readers don't know about CDNow data) and maybe the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you want 10 buckets for Recency, Frequency and Monetary Ratio:

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(
  R = runif(n, 1, 365),
  F = runif(n, 1, 5),
  M = runif(n, 0, 100)
)
apply(df, 2, function(col) {
  breaks <- quantile(col, probs=seq(0, 1, length.out = 10))
  findInterval(col, breaks)
})
```